# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session | DAO

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I searched for this problem too much, but I couldn't solve. I'm getting `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`
exception, even though I tried to initialize firma.getSektor(). 
I couldn't see any relationship or annotation problem in Sektor.java or Firma.java.
Please help me.

**Edit:** I don't have a positive look on using Eagle Loading to solve this problem because of it might decrease peformance.

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:414)
at CRMFunctions.CRMFunctions.TableDoldur(CRMFunctions.java:804)
at app.FirmaYonetim.Firmalar.<init>(Firmalar.java:138)
... 43 more
```

My Code:

```
public static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application.xml");
public static FirmaHome FIRMA_HOME = (FirmaHome) context.getBean("firmaHome");


Vector<Vector<?>> firmaData = new Vector<Vector<?>>();
        List<Firma> firmas = FIRMA_HOME.findAll();
        if (firmas.size() > 0) {
            for (Firma firma : firmas) {
                Vector vector = new Vector();
                vector.add(firma.getFirmaId());
                vector.add(firma.getFirmaUnvan());
                vector.add(firma.getFirmaVergiDairesi());
                vector.add(firma.getFirmaVergiNo());
                Hibernate.initialize(firma.getSektor());
                vector.add(firma.getSektor().getSektorAd());
                firmaData.add(vector);
            }   
        }               
        return new CRMTable(firmaData, Arrays.asList("Firma ID", "Unvan", "Vergi Dairesi", "Vergi No" ,"Sektor"), 1, new Boolean[] { false, false,
            false, false, false });
```

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="ilHome" class="dto.IlHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="anlasmaHome" class="dto.AnlasmaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="bankaHome" class="dto.BankaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="depoUrunHome" class="dto.DepoUrunHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="duyuruHome" class="dto.DuyuruHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="duyuruAliciHome" class="dto.DuyuruAliciHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="firmaHome" class="dto.FirmaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="gonderiHome" class="dto.GonderiHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="gonderiDurumHome" class="dto.GonderiDurumHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="hastalikRaporHome" class="dto.HastalikRaporHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="ilceHome" class="dto.IlceHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="kampanyaHome" class="dto.KampanyaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="kaynakHome" class="dto.KaynakHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="mahalleHome" class="dto.MahalleHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="markaHome" class="dto.MarkaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="meslekHome" class="dto.MeslekHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriHome" class="dto.MusteriHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriAdresHome" class="dto.MusteriAdresHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriKaraListeHome" class="dto.MusteriKaraListeHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriMailHome" class="dto.MusteriMailHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriTelefonHome" class="dto.MusteriTelefonHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriWebHome" class="dto.MusteriWebHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriNotHome" class="dto.MusteriNotHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriSikayetHome" class="dto.MusteriSikayetHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="musteriTakipHome" class="dto.MusteriTakipHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelHome" class="dto.PersonelHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelAdresHome" class="dto.PersonelAdresHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelBankaHesapHome" class="dto.PersonelBankaHesapHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelEskiFirmaHome" class="dto.PersonelEskiFirmaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelHastalikHome" class="dto.PersonelHastalikHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelIzinHome" class="dto.PersonelIzinHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelKaraListeHome" class="dto.PersonelKaraListeHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelMailHome" class="dto.PersonelMailHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelTelefonHome" class="dto.PersonelTelefonHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="PersonelSozlesmeHome" class="dto.PersonelSozlesmeHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelWebHome" class="dto.PersonelWebHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="personelYoklamaHome" class="dto.PersonelYoklamaHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="postaKoduHome" class="dto.PostaKoduHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="satisHome" class="dto.SatisHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="sektorHome" class="dto.SektorHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="semtHome" class="dto.SemtHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="subeHome" class="dto.SubeHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="subeAdresHome" class="dto.SubeAdresHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="subeMailHome" class="dto.SubeMailHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="subeTelefonHome" class="dto.SubeTelefonHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="subeWebHome" class="dto.SubeWebHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>


<bean id="ulkeHome" class="dto.UlkeHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>


<bean id="urunHome" class="dto.UrunHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="urunBarkodHome" class="dto.UrunBarkodHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="urunGrupHome" class="dto.UrunGrupHome">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation" expression="execution(* dto..*Home.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />-->

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.110:3306/HalfaCrmDb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>          
    <mapping class="dto.Urun" resource="dto/Urun.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelKaraListe" resource="dto/PersonelKaraListe.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelMail" resource="dto/PersonelMail.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.DuyuruAlici" resource="dto/DuyuruAlici.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Musteri" resource="dto/Musteri.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Semt" resource="dto/Semt.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Ulke" resource="dto/Ulke.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriTakip" resource="dto/MusteriTakip.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.SubeMail" resource="dto/SubeMail.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriTelefon" resource="dto/MusteriTelefon.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.DepoUrun" resource="dto/DepoUrun.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Il" resource="dto/Il.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Kampanya" resource="dto/Kampanya.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelWeb" resource="dto/PersonelWeb.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriKaraListe" resource="dto/MusteriKaraListe.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PostaKodu" resource="dto/PostaKodu.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Marka" resource="dto/Marka.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.UrunGrup" resource="dto/UrunGrup.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelTelefon" resource="dto/PersonelTelefon.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Mahalle" resource="dto/Mahalle.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Duyuru" resource="dto/Duyuru.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Firma" resource="dto/Firma.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelYoklama" resource="dto/PersonelYoklama.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.SatisUrun" resource="dto/SatisUrun.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Kaynak" resource="dto/Kaynak.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Anlasma" resource="dto/Anlasma.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriNot" resource="dto/MusteriNot.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Ilce" resource="dto/Ilce.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelBankaHesap" resource="dto/PersonelBankaHesap.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelHastalik" resource="dto/PersonelHastalik.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriSikayet" resource="dto/MusteriSikayet.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Gonderi" resource="dto/Gonderi.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelAdres" resource="dto/PersonelAdres.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.SubeTelefon" resource="dto/SubeTelefon.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriMail" resource="dto/MusteriMail.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.GonderiDurum" resource="dto/GonderiDurum.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.HastalikRapor" resource="dto/HastalikRapor.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.UrunBarkod" resource="dto/UrunBarkod.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Meslek" resource="dto/Meslek.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Personel" resource="dto/Personel.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Sektor" resource="dto/Sektor.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelSozlesme" resource="dto/PersonelSozlesme.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriAdres" resource="dto/MusteriAdres.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.SubeAdres" resource="dto/SubeAdres.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.SubeWeb" resource="dto/SubeWeb.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelEskiFirma" resource="dto/PersonelEskiFirma.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Satis" resource="dto/Satis.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Banka" resource="dto/Banka.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.PersonelIzin" resource="dto/PersonelIzin.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.MusteriWeb" resource="dto/MusteriWeb.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping class="dto.Sube" resource="dto/Sube.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

Firma.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="dto.Firma" table="Firma" catalog="HalfaCrmDb">
        <id name="firmaId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="firmaId" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="sektor" class="dto.Sektor" fetch="select">
            <column name="firmaSektorId">
                <comment>Sektor TBL'den ID gelecek</comment>
            </column>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="firmaUnvan" type="string">
            <column name="firmaUnvan" />
        </property>
        <property name="firmaVergiDairesi" type="string">
            <column name="firmaVergiDairesi" />
        </property>
        <property name="firmaVergiNo" type="string">
            <column name="firmaVergiNo" length="11" />
        </property>
        <set name="subes" table="Sube" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="subeFirmaId">
                    <comment>Firma TBL'den ID gelecek</comment>
                </column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="dto.Sube" />
        </set>
        <set name="anlasmas" table="Anlasma" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="anlasmaFirmaId">
                    <comment>Firma TBL'den ID gelecek</comment>
                </column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="dto.Anlasma" />
        </set>
        <set name="markas" table="Marka" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="markaFirmaId">
                    <comment>Firma TBL'den ID Gelecek</comment>
                </column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="dto.Marka" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Sektor.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="dto.Sektor" table="Sektor" catalog="HalfaCrmDb">
    <id name="sektorId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="sektorId" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="sektorAd" type="string">
        <column name="sektorAd" length="50" />
    </property>
    <set name="mesleks" table="Meslek" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="meslekSektorId">
                <comment>Sektor TBL'den ID gelecek</comment>
            </column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="dto.Meslek" />
    </set>
    <set name="firmas" table="Firma" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="firmaSektorId">
                <comment>Sektor TBL'den ID gelecek</comment>
            </column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="dto.Firma" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Sektor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sektor", catalog = "HalfaCrmDb")
public class Sektor implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1370608783666448790L;
private Integer sektorId;
private String sektorAd;
private Set<Meslek> mesleks = new HashSet<Meslek>(0);
private Set<Firma> firmas = new HashSet<Firma>(0);

public Sektor() {
}

public Sektor(String sektorAd, Set<Meslek> mesleks, Set<Firma> firmas) {
    this.sektorAd = sektorAd;
    this.mesleks = mesleks;
    this.firmas = firmas;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "sektorId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getSektorId() {
    return this.sektorId;
}

public void setSektorId(Integer sektorId) {
    this.sektorId = sektorId;
}

@Column(name = "sektorAd", length = 50)
public String getSektorAd() {
    return this.sektorAd;
}

public void setSektorAd(String sektorAd) {
    this.sektorAd = sektorAd;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sektor")
public Set<Meslek> getMesleks() {
    return this.mesleks;
}

public void setMesleks(Set<Meslek> mesleks) {
    this.mesleks = mesleks;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sektor")
public Set<Firma> getFirmas() {
    return this.firmas;
}

public void setFirmas(Set<Firma> firmas) {
    this.firmas = firmas;
}
}
```

Firma.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Firma", catalog = "HalfaCrmDb")
public class Firma implements java.io.Serializable {        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4310046345444125265L;
    private Integer firmaId;
    private Sektor sektor;
    private String firmaUnvan;
    private String firmaVergiDairesi;
    private String firmaVergiNo;
    private Set<Sube> subes = new HashSet<Sube>(0);
    private Set<Anlasma> anlasmas = new HashSet<Anlasma>(0);
    private Set<Marka> markas = new HashSet<Marka>(0);

    public Firma() {
    }

    public Firma(Sektor sektor, String firmaUnvan, String firmaVergiDairesi,
            String firmaVergiNo, Set<Sube> subes, Set<Anlasma> anlasmas, Set<Marka> markas) {
        this.sektor = sektor;
        this.firmaUnvan = firmaUnvan;
        this.firmaVergiDairesi = firmaVergiDairesi;
        this.firmaVergiNo = firmaVergiNo;
        this.subes = subes;
        this.anlasmas = anlasmas;
        this.markas = markas;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "firmaId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getFirmaId() {
        return this.firmaId;
    }

    public void setFirmaId(Integer firmaId) {
        this.firmaId = firmaId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "firmaSektorId")
    public Sektor getSektor() {
        return this.sektor;
    }

    public void setSektor(Sektor sektor) {
        this.sektor = sektor;
    }

    @Column(name = "firmaUnvan")
    public String getFirmaUnvan() {
        return this.firmaUnvan;
    }

    public void setFirmaUnvan(String firmaUnvan) {
        this.firmaUnvan = firmaUnvan;
    }

    @Column(name = "firmaVergiDairesi")
    public String getFirmaVergiDairesi() {
        return this.firmaVergiDairesi;
    }

    public void setFirmaVergiDairesi(String firmaVergiDairesi) {
        this.firmaVergiDairesi = firmaVergiDairesi;
    }

    @Column(name = "firmaVergiNo", length = 11)
    public String getFirmaVergiNo() {
        return this.firmaVergiNo;
    }

    public void setFirmaVergiNo(String firmaVergiNo) {
        this.firmaVergiNo = firmaVergiNo;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "firma")
    public Set<Sube> getSubes() {
        return this.subes;
    }

    public void setSubes(Set<Sube> subes) {
        this.subes = subes;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "firma")
    public Set<Anlasma> getAnlasmas() {
        return this.anlasmas;
    }

    public void setAnlasmas(Set<Anlasma> anlasmas) {
        this.anlasmas = anlasmas;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "firma")
    public Set<Marka> getMarkas() {
        return this.markas;
    }

    public void setMarkas(Set<Marka> markas) {
        this.markas = markas;
}
```

GenericDao.java

```
public interface GenericDao<E, PK extends Serializable> 
{
PK save(E newInstance);

void update(E transientObject);

void saveOrUpdate(E transientObject);

void delete(E persistentObject);

E findById(PK id);

List<E> findAll();

List<E> findAllByProperty(String propertyName, Object value);
}
```

GenericDaoImpl.java

```
    public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, PK extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDao<E, PK>
{


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public PK save(E newInstance) {
    return (PK) getHibernateTemplate().save(newInstance);
}

public E findById(PK id) {
    return (E) getHibernateTemplate().get(getEntityClass(), id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findAll() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(createDetachedCriteria());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findAllByProperty(String propertyName, Object value) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = createDetachedCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(propertyName, value));
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findByExample(E object) {
    List<E> resultList = getHibernateTemplate().findByExample(object, 0, 1);
    return resultList;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> findByExample(E object, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
    List<E> resultList = getHibernateTemplate().findByExample(object,
            firstResult, maxResults);
    return resultList;
}

public void update(E transientObject) {
    getHibernateTemplate().update(transientObject);
}

public void saveOrUpdate(E transientObject) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(transientObject);
}

public void delete(E persistentObject) {
    getHibernateTemplate().delete(persistentObject);
}

protected abstract Class<E> getEntityClass();

protected DetachedCriteria createDetachedCriteria() {
    return DetachedCriteria.forClass(getEntityClass());
}
}
```

FirmaHome.java

```
public class FirmaHome extends GenericDaoImpl<Firma, Integer> {

@Override
protected Class<Firma> getEntityClass() {
    return Firma.class;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there anybody to help me?

Comment: can you edit the question and post the code of `FIRMA_HOME.findAll()`?

Comment: I did it. Also I posted 'application.xml' and 'hibernate.cfg.xml'.

Comment: GenericDao, GenericaoImpl and FırmaHome codes are posted. I think there is no absent now. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I didn't use Hibernate for quite a few months now and I can't test anything right now, so my answer will probably not be really helpful but hey maybe I will give you a hint :

Last time I had this error it was because I was trying to get data with lazy loading AFTER the transaction was closed. I had a method with the @Transactional annotation (so a transaction was opened then closed before and after the method) and somehow I was trying to load my data after that transactional method. But it was with Spring framework so I have no idea how works with a plain hibernate... Either you find a way around in your code to avoid this, or you can just avoid lazy loading and try an EAGER FetchType in your @OneToMany.

I realize this isn't really helpful (it's ok you can downvote guys) I'm really sorry but I just can't get my hand on a working hibernate mapping from my previous projects...

Comment: Where should I put @Transactional annotation?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified it earlier : I was using Hibernate (implementing JPA) with the Spring framework (this annotation is from Spring). I have never encountered this "could not initialize proxy" error with a good old hibernate mapping file so I can only give you the theory. But the fact remains : you are trying to load a lazy method after your transaction has been closed.

Comment: Can you tell me how to load the lazy method before transaction closed?

Comment: First could you tell us which method does this exactly ? The exception doesn't show a specific line. If you don't know which one you will have to debug it step by step.

Comment: CRMFunctions.java Line: 804 -> Hibernate.initialize(firma.getSektor());

Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:414)
at CRMFunctions.CRMFunctions.TableDoldur(CRMFunctions.java:804)
at app.FirmaYonetim.Firmalar.<init>(Firmalar.java:138)
... 43 more

Comment: Ok I will probably ask a silly question but since I never used Hibernate without Spring : how do you handle transactions ? Like, when do you open and close them ? In your code I never see anything related to EntityTransaction like persist, commit, etc. We need to step back a little to understand why your lazy method "getSektor()" can't get load.

Comment: Hey, as you can see I'm new in spring and hibernate. I have no code for handling transactions. Only I have save, find etc. in GenericDaoImpl. I can get Firma record from database without any transaction code but I cannot get Firma's Sektors.. I didn't know I need a code for handling transactions. Can you give me an example for handling Transactions? Forgive me, let me tell you one more time; I'm new in Spring and Hiberante and it means my questions might be silly for you.

Comment: Well the problem is that I'm quite new to Spring+Hibernate too since I used it only like 6 months (and it was a few months ago) so I'm barely better than you ! Well if you use Spring too (I didn't even knew, your code doesn't show it) then you have access to the @Transactional annotation ! Go check it out, it's supposed to handle all your transactions thanks to Spring so you don't have to open and close manually your transactions. Go check also the filter "OpenSessionInViewFilter", if I remember correctly it helped me for this problem. I hope it will help, I'm afraid I can't do more :/

Comment: Ok my bad, it was written all over that you were using Spring. Like I said, it was a few months ago and it seems I'm quite tired... :o) Well then, like I said it will be easier to help you : Go check @Transactional and more importantly "OpenSessionInViewFilter" ;)

Comment: I'll check all of them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's okay I did what I could. Don't forget to come back and post the answer if you manage to solve the problem by your own ;)

Comment: I've just added code for handling transactions to my application.xml as explained in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html, It gives same exception. It still says could not initialize proxy - no Session.
I' m just really going crazy right now

Comment: You're right. My problem was I passed the Entity beyond the DAO layer and tried to access it elsewhere. It was outside of the context of the "Transaction". Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

The session is configured to be started *automatically* inside any service method by the configuration         `<tx:method name="*" />`

The issue is that you are invoking the `Hibernate.initialize` outside a service method which doesn't have a session anymore.

My suggestion for you is to create a method inside the `FirmaHome` service to return the `Vector` of firmas. Example:

```
    public Vector<Vector<?>> loadFirmas(){ 
            Vector<Vector<?>> firmaData = new Vector<Vector<?>>();
            List<Firma> firmas = FIRMA_HOME.findAll();
            if (firmas.size() > 0) {
                for (Firma firma : firmas) {
                    Vector vector = new Vector();
                    vector.add(firma.getFirmaId());
                    vector.add(firma.getFirmaUnvan());
                    vector.add(firma.getFirmaVergiDairesi());
                    vector.add(firma.getFirmaVergiNo());
                    Hibernate.initialize(firma.getSektor());
                    vector.add(firma.getSektor().getSektorAd());
                    firmaData.add(vector);
                }   
            }     
    }
```

*ps: I am not sure, but I think that by moving this method to a service you wont need to invoke the Hibernate.initialize*

Comment: Now, I'm traying to iplement google generic dao. I gave up using previous old dao. Thank you.